# Identitity operator-state mapping in CFT

Tags: conformal-field-theory

In a general CFT, how can the identity operator be mapped into a state?
Can you give examples to demonstrate the systematic way to do the mapping?
Take 2D CFT (in String Theory) as examples. For X-CFT, $\hat{1}$ is mapped to the ground state $|0>_X$; for bc-CFT, $\hat{1}$ is mapped to $b_{-1}|\downarrow>_{gh}$.

Comment: Related : (http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/88777/6316)