# Operator-state correspondence in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory

Operator-state correspondence is usual in $d\geq 2$. See for example [Operator-state correspondence in QFT](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/88773/operator-state-correspondence-in-qft).

Is some kind of Operator-state correspondence in 1d CFT or more generally in quantum mechanics? Is such correspondence for SYK model?

In CFT essential step is radial quantisation. What is analogue in QM?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Indeed there is a version of the state operator correspondence that holds in 1d CFT/Quantum mechanics. Note that operator -> state map is trivially true in any general QFT in arbitrary dimensions. However, state -> operator map is the non-trivial bit that holds only in a CFT, and follows from scale invariance as depicted by the diagram in your question. In a 1-dimensional theory, due to lack of spatial dimensions, it is always possible to associate a state with an operator insertion. So my guess would be, that it is more generally true. However, a correspondence akin to the one in higher dimensions is discussed in https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.4254. You will find that in the case of 1-dimensional conformal theory, a operator insertion corresponds to a state in a double copy of theory.